# CSS - Borders not hide in Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

All images on site have a border property of `border: 2px solid;`.
Expected result is that what I want to hide is hidden and not showing.
I hide with below but are there any type of `-webkit-` for this? Google isn't showing any useful results.

```
height: 0;
display: none;
border: 0;
```

This works in all browsers except the iOS Safari.

When `Toggle = hide`:

[image: When <code>Toggle = hide</code>]

When `Toggle = show`:

[image: When <code>Toggle = show</code>]

I have included a snippet with the problem. Please toggle the first four "Se mere" from top after you have toggled the "See more big".

```css
.wrapper-wrap img {
 border: 2px solid #2E181A;
  margin: 0px 15px 15px 15px;
  display: inline;
 width: 200px
 height: auto;
 text-align: center;
}


/*=============== READ MORE READ LESS ============*/
/******************** Danish **********************/
/*************** See more wrapper *****************/
/**************************************************/

.wrapper-state {
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target {
 opacity: 0;
 height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-wrap {
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap {
 display: block;
}

.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .wrapper-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-trigger:before {
 content: 'See more big';
}

.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-trigger:before {
 content: 'Luk afsnit';
}

.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-trigger2:before {
 content: 'See more big';
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-trigger2:before {
 content: 'Luk afsnit';
 display: inline-block;
}

.wrapper-trigger, .wrapper-trigger2 {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

.wrapper-trigger2:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more first ******/
/*********************/

.first-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .first-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.first-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-wrap .first-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}


.first-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.first-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.first-state ~ .first-wrap {
 display: none;
}

.first-state:checked ~ .first-wrap {
 display: block;
}

.first-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.first-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.first-target p {
 display: none;
}

.first-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-target p {
 display: block;
}

.first-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.first-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .first-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .first-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .first-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more second ******/
/*********************/

.second-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .second-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.second-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-wrap .second-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.second-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.second-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.second-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.second-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.second-target p {
 display: none;
}

.second-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-target p {
 display: block;
}

.second-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.second-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .second-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .second-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .second-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more third ******/
/*********************/

.third-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .third-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.third-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-wrap .third-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.third-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.third-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.third-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.third-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.third-target p {
 display: none;
}

.third-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-target p {
 display: block;
}

.third-target iframe {
  height: 0;
}

.third-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .third-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .third-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .third-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more fourth ******/
/*********************/

.fourth-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .fourth-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.fourth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-wrap .fourth-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.fourth-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.fourth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.fourth-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.fourth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.fourth-target p {
 display: none;
}

.fourth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-target p {
 display: block;
}

.fourth-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.fourth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fourth-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .fourth-trigger {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  background-color:#2E181A;
  color: #E6D9BD;
  font-size: .9em;
  line-height: 2;
  border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .fourth-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more fifth ******/
/*********************/

.fifth-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .fifth-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.fifth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-wrap .fifth-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.fifth-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.fifth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.fifth-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.fifth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.fifth-target p {
 display: none;
}

.fifth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-target p {
 display: block;
}

.fifth-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.fifth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .fifth-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .fifth-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .fifth-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more sixth ******/
/*********************/

.sixth-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .sixth-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.sixth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-wrap .sixth-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.sixth-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.sixth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.sixth-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.sixth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.sixth-target p {
 display: none;
}

.sixth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-target p {
 display: block;
}

.sixth-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.sixth-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .sixth-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .sixth-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .sixth-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more seventh ******/
/*********************/

.seventh-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .seventh-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.seventh-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-wrap .seventh-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.seventh-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.seventh-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.seventh-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.seventh-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.seventh-target p {
 display: none;
}

.seventh-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-target p {
 display: block;
}

.seventh-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.seventh-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .seventh-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .seventh-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .seventh-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more eight ******/
/*********************/

.eight-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .eight-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.eight-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-wrap .eight-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.eight-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.eight-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.eight-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.eight-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.eight-target p {
 display: none;
}

.eight-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-target p {
 display: block;
}

.eight-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.eight-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .eight-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .eight-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .eight-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more nine ******/
/*********************/

.nine-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .nine-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.nine-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-wrap .nine-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.nine-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.nine-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.nine-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.nine-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.nine-target p {
 display: none;
}

.nine-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-target p {
 display: block;
}

.nine-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.nine-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .nine-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .nine-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .nine-trigger:hover {
  border: 1px solid #2E181A;
  background-color: #E6D9BD;
  opacity: 1;
  color:#2E181A;
}

/****** See more ten ******/
/*********************/

.ten-state{
 display: none;
}

.wrapper-target .ten-target {
 opacity: 0;
 max-height: 0;
 font-size: 0;
 transition: .25s ease;
}

.ten-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-wrap .ten-target {
 opacity: 1;
 font-size: inherit;
 max-height: 999em;
}

.ten-state ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mere';
}

.ten-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-trigger:before {
 content: 'Se mindre';
}

.ten-target img {
 height: 0;
}

.ten-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-target img {
 height: auto;
}

.ten-target p {
 display: none;
}

.ten-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-target p {
 display: block;
}

.ten-target iframe {
 height: 0;
}

.ten-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap .ten-target iframe {
 height: 100%;
}

.wrapper-wrap .ten-trigger {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 0 .5em;
 background-color:#2E181A;
 color: #E6D9BD;
 font-size: .9em;
 line-height: 2;
 border: 1px solid #E6D9BD;
 border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.wrapper-wrap .ten-trigger:hover {
 border: 1px solid #2E181A;
 background-color: #E6D9BD;
 opacity: 1;
 color:#2E181A;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="wrapper-state" id="post-wrap" />
<input type="checkbox" class="first-state" id="post-1" />
<input type="checkbox" class="second-state" id="post-2" />
<input type="checkbox" class="third-state" id="post-3" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fourth-state" id="post-4" />
<input type="checkbox" class="fifth-state" id="post-5" />
<input type="checkbox" class="sixth-state" id="post-6" />
<input type="checkbox" class="seventh-state" id="post-7" />
<input type="checkbox" class="eight-state" id="post-8" />
<input type="checkbox" class="nine-state" id="post-9" />
<input type="checkbox" class="ten-state" id="post-10" />

<p>What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
  specimen book.</p>

<hr />

<label for="post-wrap" class="wrapper-trigger"></label>

<div class="wrapper-wrap">
  <span class="wrapper-target">

<div class="first-wrap">
<span class="first-target">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="auto" width="250px" />
<p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-1" class="first-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="second-wrap">
  <span class="second-target">
<h3>Why do we use it?</h3>
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="auto" width="250px" />
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English.</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-2" class="second-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="third-wrap">
  <span class="third-target">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="auto" width="250px" />
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-3" class="third-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="fourth-wrap">
  <span class="fourth-target">
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="auto" width="250px" />
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-4" class="fourth-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="fifth-wrap">

  <span class="fifth-target">
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vNJnOfyhweo" frameborder="0" tabindex="-1" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-5" class="fifth-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="sixth-wrap">
  <span class="sixth-target">
<h1>Where does it come from?</h1>
<p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-6" class="sixth-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="seventh-wrap">

  <span class="seventh-target">
<p>Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-7" class="seventh-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="eight-wrap">
  <span class="eight-target">
<p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-8" class="eight-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="nine-wrap">

  <span class="nine-target">
<p>The nine riders......</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-9" class="nine-trigger"></label>

<hr />

<div class="ten-wrap">
  <span class="ten-target">
<p>OMFG... Finally at the end!</p>
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-10" class="ten-trigger"></label>

<hr />
</span>
</div>
<label for="post-wrap" class="wrapper-trigger2"></label>
<div class="clearer"></div>
```

Comment: Not 100% what you mean, but try `border:none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean you don't want to see any border when everything is collapsed?
Than you could hide the first hr element after the label when the input isn't checked.

```
.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-wrap label + hr {
     display: none;
}

.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-wrap label + hr {
     display: block;
}
```

And also these labels with the wrapper-trigger classes should have no border when nothing has been checked:

```
.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-trigger,
.wrapper-state ~ .wrapper-trigger2 {
     border: 0;
}
.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-trigger,
.wrapper-state:checked ~ .wrapper-trigger2 {
     border: 1px solid #E6D98D;
}
```

Comment: The problem only exist on Safari browser. The borders around the images that I hide is still shown when the image is hide. The reference with the `<hr>` was only for given an idea of the problem for the non-Safari users...

Comment: You mean there is still this 'height' because of the margins and 2*2=4px border of the image when it's hidden?  It's because even the height of the image is set to 0, it still has a display: inline;  I think you can solve it (in Safari) to give the wrapping span (for example .wrapper-target .second-target) a  display: block; overflow: hidden; . That way the space of the border and margin of img will not be present.  
I hope I do understand it now and that this will solve the problem.

Comment: I have updated question with pictures describe the problem. Setting `overflow: hidden;` didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hm too bad.. 
What version of Safari is this and what kind of device did you use?

Comment: I forgot to clear the cache. Setting `display: none;` works! Yet I'd to set the margins differently but that is no problem :) Thank you.